# Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure doesn't contain type or namespace 'AzureTableStorage'

Tags: asp.net-core, botframework, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, manage-nuget-packages

Earlier nuget package '**Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure**' had AzureTableStorage, AzureBlobStorage and CosmosDbStorage but now the **latest version has only AzureBlobStorage and CosmosDbStorage .**
What if I need to used the TableStorage also the **IStorage of Microsoft.Bot.Builder.IStorage doesn't allow table storage but only blob and cosmos dB storage**.
Is table storage not supported for IStorage or am I missing something?
I have also tried upgrading all nuget packages and used target framework .NET Core 2.2

Comment: I am  just started using Bot framework SDK V4 and blob storage is working fine but I have no clue for table storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provider for table storage was removed before the SDK was released due to limitations that the team didn't have time to work around. That said, as you can see, there is an `IStorage` abstraction that would allow you to write your own implementation on top of Azure Table Storage if that's something you think you need.

Honestly, I don't know if I see much of a point in it. If you don't need the ability to perform ad-hoc queries over the data then blob storage is the cheapest, fastest option. If you do want to perform ad-hoc queries over the data, then table storage was never going to help you anyway due to it only having partition/row key indexability, so you'd need to go to something more powerful like CosmosDB which can index on all of the data.

FWIW, if you wanted to resurrect the `AzureTableStorage` implementation, you can always grab [the last version that existed before it was removed from the SDK here](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/73d1d98173a82da84f3795cbdd0d473ca97bef4f/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure/AzureTableStorage.cs).

Comment: Thanks for your guidance